# How to keep hostname on title when I run commands

Tags: zsh, putty, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying zsh on Ubuntu 20.04 from Putty. One good feature I like is that zsh automatically show the running command on window title, which is good for forgetful me who forget what is running.

[image]

Nonetheless, I would like to append username and hostname to the running command.

As the screenshot shows, what I'm running is htop. Can zsh  set title to, say, `gqqnbig@tatooine:~ htop`, like the title says when I'm not running anything?

[image]

I'm also using oh-my-zsh.

**Response to Marlon Richert**

Yes, I'm using Putty. If I use Bash, as the screenshots show, Putty fails to set the Window title. Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Zsh doesn't set your terminal's title. That's your terminal that does that. Which terminal do you use? (It looks like PuTTY?) Please update your answer.

Comment: @MarlonRichert See my update.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add which operating system you use? And did it come with Zsh pre-installed or did you install it yourself? If the latter, how did you install Zsh? It would help me figure out why the behavior in PuTTY is different between Bash and Zsh.

Comment: @MarlonRichert I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I use apt install zsh and oh-my-zsh is installed via https://ohmyz.sh#install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One good feature I like is that zsh automatically show the running command on window title

That's actually Oh-My-Zsh that does that, not Zsh itself.

To get the behavior you want:

1. From the Oh-My-Zsh file [`lib/termsupport.zsh`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh), copy the function `omz_termsupport_preexec` to your `.zshrc` file
2. Change the last line (`title '$CMD' '%100>...>$LINE%<<'`) to

   ```bsh
   title "$ZSH_THEME_TERM_TITLE_IDLE $CMD" \
         "%100>...>$ZSH_THEME_TERM_TAB_TITLE_IDLE $LINE%<<"
   ```

Comment: I find I had to change the second argument to ZSH_THEME_TERM_TITLE_IDLE.